# NX genenerator throws error when i try to add a value flag in schema.json

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

I'm on version 15 of NX, its a monorepo for react components. With the NX plugin i created a local generator.

This generator should have 2 value flags `--name` and `--version`.
However when I populate these flags, I get this error:

> Executing task: npx nx generate @design-system/components-library:new-component --name=fffff --version=ggggg --no-interactive --dry-run
>
> NX  Generating @design-system/components-library:new-component
> NX   Property 'version' does not match the schema. 'false' should be a 'string'.

This is the schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
  "id": "MyGenerator",
  "title": "My Generator Options Schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The name of the project",
      "x-prompt": "What is the name of the project?"
    },
    "version": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The version of the project",
      "x-prompt": "What is the version of the project?"
    }
  },
  "required": ["name", "version"]
}
```

This is the generator file, its a demo. I also tried to take the one from the NRWL library but i get the same error

```
import {
  Tree,
  formatFiles,
  installPackagesTask,
  generateFiles,
  joinPathFragments,
  names
} from '@nrwl/devkit';

interface Schema {
  name: string; // The name of the project
  version: string; // The version of the project
}

export default async function (host: Tree, opts: Schema) {
  const templateOptions = {
    ...opts,
    ...names(opts.name), // this will generate the name in various formats (e.g., normal, kebab-case, camelCase)
    tmpl: '', // in order to use the 'tmpl' prefix for the template files
  };

  generateFiles(
    host, // the file system tree
    joinPathFragments(__dirname, 'files'), // path to the files for this schematic
    joinPathFragments('apps', opts.name), // destination path
    templateOptions, // template options that will be used to render the files
  );

  // format all the created or updated files
  await formatFiles(host);

  // install the npm packages (if any)
  return () => {
    installPackagesTask(host);
  }
}
```

Well I tried to check the NX components folder on github, but I also got a similar output.

The code does not even go through the generator - it breaks before.

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it, so nx has also a variable name which is named version, this of course creates a colision.

so the solution is to give the variable a different name